# Number of increasing subsequences in sequence of [0-9] elements

Tags: algorithm

In the case a sequence of unknown range value elements, the question [Number of all increasing subsequences in given sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4636372/number-of-all-increasing-subsequences-in-given-sequence) give us a solution in O(n^2).

I've heard of a solution in O(9*n) in the case of a sequence composed of elements in the interval [0,9] only. If you know this algorithm please let me know about that.

Comment: If n=9 for the interval [0,9], doesn't that mean that O(9*n) is still just O(n^2)?

Comment: the number of elements of the sequence n can be as large as 10^5. the [0-9] interval is the value of the elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an algorithm:

1)Let's call `dp[i]` = the number of increasing subsequences which have a last element `i`(`0 <= i <= 9`). Initially it is filled with zeros.

2)Now we can iterate over the sequence and compute `dp` in the following way:
Let's assume that the current element is `d`(`0 <= d <= 9`). Then `dp` can be updated like this:

```
for prev = 0...d - 1
    dp[d] += dp[prev] //continue one of the previous sequences.
dp[d] += 1 //start a new sequence that consists of only one element.
```

3)After iterating over all the elements of the sequence,
 the answer is just the sum of `dp[i]` for `0 <= i <= 9`.

Note that this algorithm has desired complexity only under assumption that arithmetic operations have `O(1)` time complexity(that might not be the case because the number of increasing subsequences can be very large).

Answer (score 1):

Altering the algorithm linked to in the question, I believe this shall also fulfill the complexity requirement:

```
input[i] = input array
n = size of input
dp[i] = number of increasing subsequences with i as the last element (same size as input)

initialize dp[i] = 0 for all 0 <= i < n

//Every possible input can be appended on to one previously found
//  increasing subsequence
for (j = 0; j <= 9; j++) {

  //Running total of increasing subsequences that occur earlier in the input using
  //  smaller numbers than j
  int smallerSum = 0;

  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {

    //This spot in dp was tallied already, need to add it to the running total
    if (input[i] < j) {
      smallerSum += dp[i]

    //Add 1 to the running total, this should be the final answer for this spot in dp
    } else if (input[i] == j) {
      dp[i] = smallerSum + 1;
    }
  }
}

return the sum of all elements of dp
```

Normally a nested for-loop is a dead giveaway of O(n^2) but in this case we're looping over a constant, making it O(n).

In the general case this algorithm would be O(n*k), where n is the size of the input array and k is the number of possible input values.