# Count triplets which satisfy given condition

Tags: c++, algorithm, dynamic-programming

Given an array `A` of size `N` I need to count such triplets (`i`,`j`,`k`) such that:

```
Condition 1 : i < j < k
Condition 2 : A[i] > A[j] > A[k]
```

I know a `O(N^3)` solution to do it. Can their be something like `O(N)` or `O(NlogN)` solution to do this problem as `N` can be up to `100000`

**Example :** Let `N=4` and array be `[4,3,2,1]` then answer is 4 as `{4,3,2}`,`{4,3,1}`,`{4,2,1}` and `{3,2,1}` are all possible answers

How to find this count for given `N` and array `A`?

**My Approach :**

```
int n;
cin>>n;
vector<int> A(n);
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    cin>>A[i];
}
int count=0;
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    for(int j=i+1;j<n;j++){
        for(int k=j+1;k<n;k++){
            if(A[i]>A[j] && A[j]>A[k]){
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
}
cout<<count<<"\n";
```

Comment: What should be done about duplicates? Should [4,2,2,1] return 1 or 2?

Comment: @JonathanMee The problem statement seems clear to me: `A[0]>A[1]>A[3]` and `A[0]>A[2]>A[3]`, so the answer is `2`. It is "count the sets of indices ...", not "count the sets of values in the array ...".

Comment: @JonathanMee Right the answer will be 2

Comment: What else can you tell us about your input? What is the range of the numbers?

Comment: Why wouldn't you read [an editorial](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/triplets/editorial) if you can't solve it by yourself.

Comment: @dubov94 no, this is not that problem, your problem require `A[i] < A[j] < A[k]` and it must be distinct triplet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, sort the array, maintain the index of each element.

```
class Node{
    int index, val;
}
```

For comparing two nodes, we first need to compare their values. If the values equals, we will compare their index, consider a node is **greater** if its index is **smaller**.

Now, process each node in sorted order, we try to add each node's index into a [Fenwick tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fenwick_tree). So, for each index `i`, we query the tree for the **frequency** of this index, which added previously in the tree. This is the number of index that has value greater than value of the current index.

**Note** for the case elements have equal value, by the sorting mechanism mentioned above, we will add those have greater index to the tree first, thus, doesn't affect the frequency value query from the tree.

Apply similar step to obtains those elements that smaller than `i` and has index `j < i`.

For example:

If we have an array

```
{0(1) ,1(2) , 2(2) ,3(4) , 4(4) ,5(4) ,6(1)} //index(value)

After sort -> {5(4), 4(4), 3(4), 2(2), 1(2), 6(1), 0(1) }
```

Pseudo code

```
Node[]data;

sort(data)
Fenwick tree;
int[]less;
int[]more;
for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    less[data[i].index] = tree.query(data[i].index);
    tree.add(data[i].index, 1);
}

tree.clear();
for(int i = data.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
    more[data[i].index] = tree.query(data.length) -tree.query(data[i].index);
    tree.add(data[i].index, 1);
}
int result = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
    result += more[i]*less[i];
```

Time complexity will be O(n logn).

Working Java code (FT is my Fenwick tree)

```
    PrintWriter out;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    out = new PrintWriter(System.out);
    int n = in.nextInt();
    Node[] data = new Node[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        data[i] = new Node(i + 1, in.nextInt());
    }
    FT tree = new FT(n + 2);
    Arrays.sort(data, new Comparator<Node>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Node o1, Node o2) {
            if (o1.val != o2.val) {
                return o2.val - o1.val;
            }
            return o2.index - o1.index;
        }
    });

    int[] less = new int[n];//Store all nodes with greater index and smaller value;
    int[] greater = new int[n];//Store all nodes with smaller index and greater value
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        greater[data[i].index - 1] = (int) tree.get(data[i].index);
        tree.update(data[i].index, 1);
    }
    tree = new FT(n + 2);
    for (int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        less[data[i].index - 1] = (int) (tree.get(n) - tree.get(data[i].index));
        tree.update(data[i].index, 1);
    }


    long total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        total += less[i] * greater[i];
    }
    out.println(total);
    out.close();
```

Comment: Why sort two times ? Is their any difference between both of them ?

Comment: @user3840069 you are correct, this seems unnecessary :), updated my code

Comment: Great Idea..Let me code it first if I face any problem will ask you otherwise will accept this answer..:)

Comment: @user3840069 be extremely careful to handle those indexes, they are the hardest part, IMO :)

Comment: Is this range add to Fenwick tree or point update ??Also what about query ?

Comment: Hey you looked code ?

Comment: @user3840069 definitely should be something wrong in the calculating larger part, so, wait for me, I will try to come up with a working code :)

Comment: @PhamTrung So I studied the Fenwick Tree [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/binary-indexed-tree-or-fenwick-tree-2/) but as I understand it the Fenwick Tree is for finding the prefix sum? How does that help us here?

Comment: @user3840069 I was able to understand and explain the binary index tree code, but I had to use one binary index tree for sub strings of length 1, 2, and 3. You can find my code and explanation here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28379003/2642059 I have also updated my answer to include an explanation how to make that an increasing rather than a decreasing sequence. Hopefully Pham can demonstrate a solution that doesn't require multiple trees though. That's something I'd be really excited about so stay tuned here too!

Comment: @JonathanMee done, added working java code :)

Comment: @user3840069 done, added working java code, hopefully you can compare it with your current code :)

Comment: @JonathanMee , for this problem we use Fenwick tree to record the number of occurrence of all indexes that less than a specific index `i`, which has been added to the tree in sorted order.

Comment: @PhamTrung It looks like you have a really slick solution here. It's been years since I've programmed in Java though, so I'm trying to keep up. What does your `Array.sort` line do? I'm assuming that your implementation of a Fenwick Tree is pretty straight forward? Could you post that as well?

Comment: @JonathanMee I have put my Fenwick tree implementation into the answer, `Array.sort` will sort the array `data`.

Comment: @PhamTrung +1 for a well thought out solution. This solution leverages the fact that the OP is only seeking three length strings to limit the number of trees required to 2, rather than the 3 [my solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28379003/2642059) requires. I wish it had been in C++ though, since this is a C++ question. Also, I'd recommend removing the pseudo-code and the results. They needlessly clutter an already long post.

Comment: @JonathanMee thanks Jonathan, unfortunately, my C++ skill is not that good, compared to my Java skill, so it's hard for me to come up with similar-quality C++ code. However, I try to cut off the output, as well as the standard Fenwick tree, which could make the answer looks better. The Pseudo code is still there, which hopefully will profit someone who cannot understand java syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in *O(n*n)* pretty easily, you just need to keep track of how many smaller number each element had:

```
vector<int> smallerNumbers(A.size());

for (int i = A.size() - 2; i >= 0; --i){
    for (int j = i + 1; j < A.size(); ++j){
        if (A[i] > A[j]){
            smallerNumbers[i]++;
            count += smallerNumbers[j];
        }
    }
}
```

For an *O(nklogn)* solution see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28379003/2642059

Note that is for an increasing sequence and you're asking for a decreasing sequence.

To accomplish that you will need to reverse the ranking created by `mapIndex`. So simply reverse `temp` before creating `mapIndex` by swapping the `partial_sort_copy` line with this one:

```
   partial_sort_copy(values.cbegin(), values.cend(), temp.rbegin(), temp.rend());
```